# redirect the url by subdomains in phpfox

Tags: php, oop, phpfox

hi i installed phpfox it really works nice . i had one big problem i already searched in all forum but my problem not resolved still. my issue is i instal the phpfox in my server and also create a subdomain named phpfox.Now just i want to view all the page through the subdomain like - >
currently it redirect the webpages like this

http://www.example.com/phpfox/index.php?do=/user/browse/

but i want

http://www.phpfox.example.com/index.php?do=/user/browse/

i already change the $_CONF['core.url_rewrite'] = 3 in the server.sett.php
still no use !! if there is any link to solve my issue means please provide me

Comment: core.url_rewrite = 3 is meant when phpfox is in the top folder, not in a "phpfox" folder. Try a normal htaccess redirect so phpfox.example.com loads your phpfox site first, then try changing the core.url_rewrite

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using cpanel for this website. If that is the case then creating a subdomain in cpanel will only result in a redirect. If you want a full subdomain that doesn't redirect it needs to have its own cpanel account. That has to be created in the WHM.